# Displaying Multiple PushPins on powerapps BingMaps using a collection

Tags: bing-maps, connector, powerapps

I have used a flow to return my list of locations with their co-ordinates in a collection and Now i am trying to display them on to a map using BingMaps.   "Mylist" is the collection name, but i am not sure on the correct syntax to get them to display required parametres.

```
BingMaps.GetMap("CanvasLight",15,Location.Latitude,Location.Longitude,
{pushpin: Concat(mylist.Lat&","& mylist.Long,";37",";\r\n")})
```

My collection in powerapps looks like this.
[powerapps collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf0wk.png)

here is a link to the syntax for pushpin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/pushpin-syntax-a...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you to get the multiple pushpins in the map

"https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Aerial/Location of the static map/4?optimize=distance&dpi=Large&mapSize=550,400&key=" & BingMapsKey &"&pp" & Concat(MyList,"=" & Latitude & "," & Longitude &";" &22&"&pp")